# index of Most-right smallest element in sorted array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a big sorted array, and i want to find the index of most right smallest element fast. O(logn)

For example

```
INDEX: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
VALUE: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 8  9  9 10 ......... N

The answer is 7
```

My opinion is binary search but I have doubts

Comment: My suggestion would be a binary search followed by linear scan to find the last tie. Complexity will be O(logn + max_run_length)

Comment: Yes but is O(n) because it needs linear scan

Comment: It will be O(n) only if the maximum run length is O(n). You only need to scan until the value changes.

Comment: What about divide and conquer?

Comment: Actually, forget about binary search. You're looking for the smallest value, so just scan from the beginning until the value changes. Complexity is O(max_run_length). Actually, O(average number of smallest element occurences)

Comment: I agree with you but is O(n). 
Think that the array has millions of items, and that the search is n times

Comment: The array may have millions of items, but if the smallest item occurs only five times, you only need to scan five items (well, 6, because you have to look at one more to know you're at the end).

Comment: But you still have n then. Worst case counts.

Comment: Too bad. My idea about quantum computing and grover search turned out to be wrong: Grover allows to find an element in **unsorted** data with O(n/2); respectively a quadratic speedup. But it doesn't apply to your problem then; see: https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/grovers-search-algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since input is sorted, a binary search will find solution in *O(log n)*.

For the people who think it'll be *O(n)*, because they think they have to do linear search to find boundary, you're not thinking it through.

To find boundary, you don't stop the binary search when finding index of target value. You keep performing the binary search until you look at adjacent indexes.

To illustrate (I'll leave coding as an exercise to interested parties):

```
INDEX: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
VALUE: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 8  9  9 10
```

Find smallest value at index 0, so `5`. Now search for `5` until boundary found, i.e. until adjacent indexes with value on left and higher value on right is found:

```
INDEX: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
VALUE: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 8  9  9 10
       |-----------|--------------|  Found 5, so search right
                   |-----|--------|  Found 8, so search left
                   |-|---|           Found 5, so search right
                     |-|-|           Found 6, so search left
                     |-|             Adjacent, so search complete
```

Boundary found between index 7 and 8, so last index of smallest value is: **7**

This can be generalized to find first/last index of any target number, or to find last index of number smaller than target, or first index of number greater than target, whether target number actually exists in the input.

---

**UPDATE**

Because I like the relational search operations of [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), I thought it could be fun to implement the `Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key)` equivalent methods of `ceiling()`, `floor()`, `higher()`, and `lower()`, as well as `first()` and `last()` variants of `get()`.

To only implement the main binary search logic once, I decided to use a functional interface / lambda expression to handle the compare logic. Cloning the code or using a `boolean` would likely perform better, but what the heck, I'm just having ***fun***.

So, here are the 6 binary search methods for an `int[]`, and the `private` method with the main search logic:

```
/**
 * Returns the least index in this array with value strictly equal to the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryFirst(int[] a, int key) {
    int idx = binaryCeiling(a, key);
    return (idx < 0 || a[idx] != key ? -1 : idx);
}

/**
 * Returns the greatest index in this array with value strictly equal to the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryLast(int[] a, int key) {
    int idx = binaryFloor(a, key);
    return (idx < 0 || a[idx] != key ? -1 : idx);
}

/**
 * Returns the greatest index in this array with value strictly less than the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryLower(int[] a, int key) {
    return binarySearch(a, x -> Integer.compare(x, key) < 0);
}

/**
 * Returns the greatest index in this array with value less than or equal to the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryFloor(int[] a, int key) {
    return binarySearch(a, x -> Integer.compare(x, key) <= 0);
}

/**
 * Returns the least index in this array with value greater than or equal to the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryCeiling(int[] a, int key) {
    int idx = binaryLower(a, key) + 1;
    return (idx == a.length ? -1 : idx);
}

/**
 * Returns the least index in this array with value strictly greater than the given key,
 * or {@code -1} if there is no such key.
 */
public static int binaryHigher(int[] a, int key) {
    int idx = binaryFloor(a, key) + 1;
    return (idx == a.length ? -1 : idx);
}

private static int minComp = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // For stats
private static int maxComp = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // For stats
private static int countComp = 0;               // For stats
private static int countSearch = 0;             // For stats

private static int binarySearch(int[] a, IntPredicate searchRight) {
    if (a.length == 0)
        return -1;
    int comp = 0; // For stats
    int first = 0, last = a.length - 1;
    while (first + 1 < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;
        comp++; // For stats
        if (searchRight.test(a[mid]))
            first = mid;
        else
            last = mid;
    }
    int result;
    if (first == last || first == 0) {
        comp++; // For stats
        result = (searchRight.test(a[first]) ? first : first - 1);
    } else if (last == a.length - 1) {
        comp++; // For stats
        result = (searchRight.test(a[last]) ? last : last - 1);
    } else {
        result = first;
    }
    minComp = Math.min(minComp, comp); // For stats
    maxComp = Math.max(maxComp, comp); // For stats
    countComp += comp;                 // For stats
    countSearch++;                     // For stats
    return result;
}
```

Since some people seem to have trouble accepting that complexity is *O(log n)*, I added collection of statistics to the main search logic.

Here is test code, performing 36 tests of 9 values (n=9). The search of empty input is not counted for the statistics.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("  =      =      <      <=    >=      >");
    System.out.println("First  Last   Lower  Floor Ceiling Higher  Input");
    test();
    test(1,1,1,1,1,9,9,9,9,9);
    test(1,1,1,5,5,5,9,9,9,9);
    test(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
    test(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5);
    test(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9);
    test(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    System.out.printf("%nStats: min=%d, max=%d, avg=%s%n",
                      minComp, maxComp, countComp / (double) countSearch);
}
private static void test(int... a) {
    System.out.printf("%3d%7d%7d%7d%7d%7d     %s%n",
                      binaryFirst(a, 5), binaryLast(a, 5), binaryLower(a, 5),
                      binaryFloor(a, 5), binaryCeiling(a, 5), binaryHigher(a, 5),
                      Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

*Output, searching for value 5*

```
  =      =      <      <=    >=      >
First  Last   Lower  Floor Ceiling Higher  Input
 -1     -1     -1     -1     -1     -1     []
 -1     -1      4      4      5      5     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
  3      5      2      5      3      6     [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9, 9]
 -1     -1      9      9     -1     -1     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
  0      9     -1      9      0     -1     [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
 -1     -1     -1     -1      0      0     [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
  5      5      4      5      5      6     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Stats: min=3, max=5, avg=3.75
```

As can be seen, the average search performed `3.75` compares (`log2(9) = 3.169925`), with worst case of `5` compares to perform one search.

I also did 4 different arrays of 10000 values, totally 24 searches:

```
Stats: min=14, max=15, avg=14.375
```

Again, average of `14.375` compares for searching 10000 values (`log2(10000) = 13.287712`).

I think that adequately proves my assertion of *O(log n)* complexity of a search.

---

And for full solution to the question:

```
public static int indexOfMostRightSmallest(int[] a) {
    return binaryLast(a, a[0]);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10 };
    System.out.println(indexOfMostRightSmallest(a));
}
```

*Output*

```
7

Stats: min=4, max=4, avg=4.0
```

Comment: Andrea, maybe this is O(nlogn) ?

Comment: @LeAdErQ Why would it be what? That input was 13 elements, and search completed in 4 steps. Not `13 * log2(13) = 48` steps.

Comment: If i have this array:    5 6 7 8 9 10 .... N -> infinity   the number of loops will be N  so N times call binary search.. O(nlogn)

Comment: or is O(logn logn)

Comment: @LeAdErQ If input has 10000 elements, a binary search **until adjacent elements found**, will complete in approx. `log2(10000) = 14` steps (rounded up). **_O(log n)_**. Doesn't matter if there is only 1 copy of smallest value, 5000 copies, or all 10000 values are equal. Search will take around 14 steps.

Comment: Andrea, i will try it and i will answer you, thanks in advance

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do!  With no knowledge of what binary search even was.  If anything is O(log n) doesn't it always imply this divide and conquer technique and splitting in half?

Comment: @LeAdErQ No, no.  It would be nlogn if you were applying this "halving" & recursing on both halves.  A merge sort is nlogn.  Merge sort applies this same technique, but the splitting is on both the left and right halves, and does this recursively.

Comment: @NickZiebert The standard binary search algorithm will stop when the target value is found, so performance is _O(log n)_ in worst case, but usually below that. Best case is _O(1)_, if target value is in the center. This "enhanced" binary search will continue searching, even if target value is found, because it wants last index in case of multiple copies of target value, so performance is always _O(log n)_, best case and worst case.

Comment: Andrea you said "return the smalest index", if all elements equals with five? then i must return max ? my pseudocode is this :
i=0
j = max -1 

while(!(i == j+1)):
    k = (i+j)/2
    if(A[k] == 5):
       i = k
    else:
      j = k

return i

Comment: If the number of times the O(log n) binary search has to be executed is a function of the input array (and I don't see how it can't be), then the overall complexity can't be O(log n). It seems like it wouldn't be O(n log n), but it quite likely might be O((log n)^2).

Comment: @TedHopp You're apparently reading the question differently than I am, because the question is only asking for a **single** binary search, to find the last index (7) of the smallest value (5).

Comment: @Andreas - No, that's not it. In your sketch of a solution, you clearly show multiple binary searches. How many are there (as a function of n)? That's the issue. Let's say that there are f(n) of them, where f() is some function. Then the complexity is O(f(n) log n). If f(n) is not a constant function (independent of n), then the complexity is greater than O(log n).

Comment: @TedHopp In my sketch of the solution, I clearly show ***one*** binary search, which consists of a ***single*** loop, cutting the search area in half on each iteration *(that's how [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) works)*, each cutting operation only costing ***one*** comparison operation. Unlike [code in answer by NickZiebert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43246356/5221149), no copying of data is performed, so total cost is around `log2(n)` compares to find target value in an array/list of `n` values. **_O(log n)_**